# Replace double quotes with empty string using Regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following:

```
this.LocationCode = this.LocationCode.Replace(@"""", String.Empty);
```

However I would like to use regex instead. I've used the next block of code but it doesn't do anything to the string. (They are in seperate classes but I've put them all together here for convenience)

```
public const string checkStringForDoubleQuotes = @"^[""]$";
Regex doubleQuotesPattern = new Regex(RegexChecks.checkStringForDoubleQuotes);
this.LocationCode = Regex.Replace(this.LocationCode, doubleQuotesPattern.ToString(), "");
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?
When LocationCode comes through it contains "K\"23". When I use the string replace it produces "K23" which is perfect, but the Regex way just leaves the value as it is.

**SOLUTION**

After tinkering around a little more I now have the following:

```
public const string checkStringForDoubleQuotes = @"["" ,]";
Regex doubleQuotesPattern = new Regex(RegexChecks.checkStringForDoubleQuotes )
this.LocationCode = doubleQuotesPattern.Replace(this.LocationCode, "");
```

This has allowed me to add more criteria (the comma ,) into the regex string which I wanted the option to do but realised I hadn't added that part in my question, sorry! This way is acceptable for the project, so thanks to all who helped out.

Comment: Your problem is the anchors, and also by placing your double-quote inside a character class, it will only match a single instance.  So your regex would only match a complete string that contains only a single double-quote

Comment: You are right. The ^ and $ were what was causing my issues. I hadn't realised that the [] were treating the criteria as a space delimited array. (at least that's what it looks like to me)

Answer (score 4):

The regex `^["]$` tries to match a string containing one single quote.

`"K\"23"` won't match because the double quote is not alone. Basically, the regex will only match this string: `""""` and nothing else.

The `Replace` solution is here the most straight forward solution.

---

A regex only solution would be:

```cs
public const string checkStringForDoubleQuotes = @"""";
this.LocationCode = Regex.Replace(this.LocationCode, checkStringForDoubleQuotes, string.Empty);
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/qS2aU2

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the answer but if you could point me towards a regex solution, that would be awesome.

Comment: @user2248441 I have updated my answer. Check the demo

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
s = s.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

OR

```
s = s.Replace(@"""", string.Empty);
```

Comment: With Regex, you can use:

strValue = Regex.Replace(strValue, @"([^\^,\r\n])""(?=[^$,\r\n])", @"$1");

Comment: Um, the above will replace one instance of a quote in a string. Not all instances.